# How does RailsCasts do partial page ajax?

Tags: ajax, html

Railscasts (and I've seen this technique elsewhere) seems to be modifying the URL (by adding/changing a query string) but delivers back an ajax request without reloading the entire page. How are they modifying the URL without triggering a whole page refresh? It doesn't appear at least to be using HTML5 history, since there is no history created (can't go back/forward).

http://railscasts.com/episodes/81-fixtures-in-rails-2-0

Then click any of the tabs "Show Notes", "Comments", "Similar Episodes" and watch how the query string changes, but the page does not refresh (confirmed via Firebug).

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not familiar with how it's done so I can't help you there; but, if you didn't know, the code for RailsCasts is open source: https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses [`history.replaceState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_replaceState%28%29.C2.A0method). Quoth MDC:

> `history.replaceState()` operates exactly like `history.pushState()` except that `replaceState()` modifies the current history entry instead of creating a new one.

No new history entry, nothing to go back/forward to.